# the javascript template and the event handling

Tags: javascript, templates, pagination

I have asked a question about how to avoiding to write the html in the js,then some people tell me using the javascript template,for example,the jquery/template pugin and ect.

It is a good idea when generate static html,for example:

```
<ul id="productList"></ul>

<script id="productTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li><a>${Name}</a> (${Price})</li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var products = [
        { Name: "xxx", Price: "xxx" },
        { Name: "yyy", Price: "xxx" },
        { Name: "zzz", Price: "xxx" }
    ];

    // Render the template with the products data and insert
    // the rendered HTML under the "productList" element
    $( "#productTemplate" ).tmpl( products )
        .appendTo( "#productList" );
</script>
```

However when I try to bind some event to the generated html,I meet some problem.

For example,I have a page which user can search some products by the price/name/location.

So I have three function:

```
searchByPrice(lowPrice,highPrice,productType,currentPage)
searchByName(name,productType,currentPage);
searchByLocation(location,currentpage);
```

ALl the above function have a realated method in the server side and they will retrun the products usint the xml format.

Since they will retrun so many items,so I have to paging them,the "currengPage" is used to tell the server side which part of results should be returned.

When the client get the result from the server side,now it is the js for display them int he div and create a Paging Bar if possible.

Before I know the template,I use this manner(which I hate most,try my best to avoid):

```
function searchByPrice(lowPrice,highPrice,productType,currentPage){
    var url="WebService.asmx/searchByPrice?low="+lowPrice="&high="+highPrice+"&curPage="+currentPage;
    //code to create the xmlHttp object
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var i=0;
            var Prohtml="";
            var proList=parseProductList(xmlhttp.responseText);
            for(i=0;i<prolist.length;i++){
                Prohtml+="<li><a href='#'>"+prolist[i].name+"</a> ("+prolist[i].price"+)</li>";
            }


            //generate the paging bar:
            var totleResult=getTotleResultNumber(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if(totleResult>10){
                var paghtml="<span>";
                //need the paging
                var pagNum=totleResult/10+1;
                for(i=1;i<=pagenum;i++){
                    paghtml+="<a onclick='searchByPrice(lowPrice,highPrice,productType,currentPage+1)'>i</a>";
                    //here the synax is not right,since I am really not good at handle the single or doule '"' in this manner.

                    //also if in the searchByName function,the click function here should be replaced using the searchByName(...)


                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

In the example,it is easy to use the template to generate the "Prohtml" since there is no event handling with them,but how about the "paghtml",the click function is different in differnt search type.

So,any good idea to hanld this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either:

Create DOM Elements instead of building HTML strings, using `document.createElement` or a small [library](http://microjs.com/#dom) if you're doing lots of this, which will allow you to attach events immediately in the usual fashion.

or

Give each element which needs to make use of event handlers a unique ID and build up a list of events to be attached once the HTML has been inserted into the document.

E.g.:

```
var eventHandlers = []
  , eventCount = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= pagenum; i++) {
    var id = "search" + eventCount++;
    html += "<a id='" + id + "'>" + i + "</a>";
    eventHandlers.push([id, 'click',
                        handler(searchByPrice, lowPrice, highPrice, productType, currentPage + i)])
}

// Later...
someElement.innerHTML = html;
registerEvents(eventHandlers);
```

Where `registerEvents` is:

```
function registerEvents(eventHandlers) {
  for (var i = 0, l = eventHandlers.length; i < l; i++) {
    var eventHandler = eventHandlers[i],
        id = eventHandler[0],
        eventName = eventHandler[1],
        func = eventHandler[2];
    // Where addEvent is your cross-browser event registration function
    // of choice...
    addEvent(document.getElementById(id), eventName, func);
  }
}
```

And `handler` is just a quick way to close over all the arguments passed in:

```
/**
 * Creates a fnction which calls the given function with any additional
 * arguments passed in.
 */
function handler(func) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    func.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

I use something like this approach (but automatically adding unique ids when necessary) in the HTML generation portion of my [DOMBuilder](https://github.com/insin/DOMBuilder/) library, which offers [a convenience method](http://readthedocs.org/docs/dombuilder/en/1.4.4/htmlmode.html#event-handlers-and-innerhtml) for generating HTML from content you've defined, inserting it into a given element with innerHTML and registering any event handlers which were present. Its syntax for defining content is independent of output mode, which allows you to switch between DOM and HTML output seamlessly in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can simply use the [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for your AJAX call.

Secondly, you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind events to elements that do not exist.

Thirdly, you can use the data attributes in the anchor elements as a way to pass in the arguments for the event handler, see [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

So, to rewrite your function, you have may something like the following:

```
function searchByPrice(event) {
    $this = $(this);
    var lowPrice = $this.data('lowPrice'),
        highPrice = $this.data('lowPrice'), 
        productType = $this.data('productType'),
        currentPage = $this.data('currentPage');

    var url = "WebService.asmx/searchByPrice?low=" + lowPrice = "&high=" + highPrice + "&curPage=" + currentPage;

    $.get(url, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var i = 0;
        var Prohtml = "";
        var proList = parseProductList(data);
        for (i = 0; i < prolist.length; i++) {
            Prohtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + prolist[i].name + "</a> (" + prolist[i].price "+)</li>";
        }

        //generate the paging bar:
        var totleResult = getTotleResultNumber(data);
        if (totleResult > 10) {
            var paghtml = "<span>";

            //need the paging
            var pagNum = totleResult / 10 + 1;
            for (i = 1; i <= pagenum; i++) {
                paghtml += '<a class="pagelink" ' +
                    'data-lowPrice="' + lowPrice + '" ' +
                    'data-highPrice="' + highPrice + '" ' +
                    'data-productType="' + productType + '" ' +
                    'data-currentPage="' + (currentpage + 1) + '">' + i + '</a>';
                //here the synax is not right,since I am really not good at handle the single or doule '"' in this manner.

                //also if in the searchByName function,the click function here should be replaced using the searchByName(...)

            }
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.pagelink").live('click', searchByPrice);
});
```